# Invoke-PnPQuery Permission Issue

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run the code below to update the "noCrawl" property but I am facing an issue with Invoke-PnPQuery:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -Credentials $cred
$Web = Get-PnPWeb
$Web.NoCrawl = $true
$Web.Update()
Invoke-PnPQuery
```

I get the following error

> Invoke-PnPQuery : Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.
> Au caractère Ligne:2 : 13 Invoke-PnPQuery
> CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-PnPQuery], ServerUnauthorizedAccessException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.InvokeQuery

Seems like a permissions issue, but i'm struggling with it.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figure it out.

To perform an action like to upadate "nocrawl" property, you need to have another property of the web "-DenyAndAddCustomizePages" switched to false:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $adminURL -Credentials $cred
Set-PnPSite -Identity $url -DenyAndAddCustomizePages $false
```

Then the code can be executed without any problem